# Modify a path stored in a bash script variable

Tags: bash, shell

I have a variable `f` in a bash script

`f=/path/to/a/file.jpg`

I'm using the variable as an input argument to a program that requires and input and an output path.

For example the program's usage would look like this

`./myprogram -i inputFilePath -o outputFilePath`

using my variable, I'm trying to maintain the same basename, change the extension, and put the output file into a sub directory.  For example

`./myprogram -i /path/to/a/file.jpg -o /path/to/a/new/file.tiff`

I'm trying to do that by doing this

`./myprogram -i "$f" -o "${f%.jpg}.tiff"`

of course this keeps the basename, changes the extension, but doesn't put the file into the `new` subdirectory.

How can I modify `f` to to change `/path/to/a/file.jpg` into `/path/to/a/new/file.tiff`?

Comment: Your goal is unclear. If you want to completely change `f`, you'll have to reassign it, i.e., by `f=/path/to/a/new/file.tiff`. if you want to keep some part of `f`, there are ways just as `dirname` or `basename` or your method with parameter expansion.

Comment: my goal isn't to modify `f` persay but to use the path in `f` to specify the -o path/filename

Comment: `$(dirname f)` will give you the path of `f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can do this in several ways:

1. Using `sed` as pointed out by @anubhava
2. Using `dirname` and `basename`:

   ```
   ./myprogram -i "$f" -o "$(dirname -- "$f")/new/$(basename -- "$f" .jpg).tiff"
   ```
3. Using only Bash:

   ```
   ./myprogram -i "$f" -o "${f%/*}/new/$(b=${f##*/}; echo -n ${b%.jpg}.tiff)"
   ```

Note that unlike the second solution (using `dirname/basename`) that is more robust, the third solution (in pure Bash) won't work if `"$f"` does not contain any slash:

```
$ dirname "file.jpg"
.
$ f="file.jpg"; echo "${f%/*}"
file.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `sed`:

```
s='/path/to/a/file.jpg'
sed -E 's~(.*/)([^.]+)\.jpg$~\1new/\2.tiff~' <<< "$s"
```

```
/path/to/a/new/file.tiff
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a system that supports the `basename` and `dirname`commands you could use a simple wrapper function eg:

```
$ type newSubDir
newSubDir is a function
newSubDir ()
{
    oldPath=$(dirname "${1}");
    fileName=$(basename "${1}");
    newPath="${oldPath}/${2}/${fileName}";
    echo "${newPath}"
}

$ newSubDir /path/to/a/file.jpg new
/path/to/a/new/file.jpg
```

If your system doesn't have those, you can accomplish the same thing using string manipulation:

```
$ file="/path/to/a/file.jpg"

$ echo "${file%/*}"
/path/to/a

$ echo "${file##*/}"
file.jpg
```